# What's the difference between "Taste" and "Taster"?

Tags: difference

Reading some user manuals in German, I sometimes encounter the word *Taste* and sometimes *Taster*. Is there any difference to a native German speaker?

Comment: A google search for image *Taster* provides are surprisingly detailed idea, what *Taster* means. I guess, the number of cases where *Taste* could also be considered is very small.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There actually is a difference:

*Taste* can be used for more or less anything that is operated by a finger press, e.g

- Piano key
- (mechanical) typewriter key
- key connected to a momentary electrical switch (on a computer keyboard, for example)

while *Taster* works for the momentary electrical switch only and is typically used for single switches (while the switches inside your computer keyboard might be single "Taster" in an electrical sense, the keys are referred to as "Tasten" in their mechanical sense).

So even if the two words are very similar, *Taste* would normally translate to "key" in English, while *Taster* typically translates to "(momentary) switch"

Those were the translations in terms of day-to-day usage. Translations for *Taster* can differ on whether the word is used as a technical term in mechanical or electrical context - *Taster* is also often used in mechanical engineering for instruments that "feel" a specific measure - *Innentaster* is the German technical term for "inside caliper".

Comment: According to Wikipedia, they ARE the same: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste

Comment: According to me, they aren't  ;) - I have never heard of "Klaviertaster" - But there is lots of "Klaviertasten" on a Piano.

Comment: I think, "pressed by a finger" is the most important difference. See also the meanings in Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Taster and http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Taste

Comment: So, according to the written answer I conclude that in terms of electrical devices "Taster" is an electric device which connects wires and "Taste" is a cap on a top of this device visible and touchable by an end user (an "user interface" for Taster). But this cap could be not only on a top of an electric switch, but also on a top of mechanical lever etc. Right?

Comment: @Paul That kind of sums it up for electrical or electronic devices. The usage of "Taster" in mechanical engineering is different, however.

Comment: "Taster" in the electrical context is likely an abbreviation of "Tastschalter".